# Granger causality: which kind of variables can you compare?

Tags: time-series, finance, granger-causality

Can I use Granger causality for studying if a financial variable (stock price of a company) can be caused by a non-financial variable (like the number of hours the employers work)?

Or do I have to consider my non-financial variables as exogenous variables referred to the financial variable?